# Graphical editor using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make an online card-making application. It should basically allow users to place   available images into the template of the card, write text on it and decorate it - basic card customization. What javascript graphics library would be useful for this project ? Finally I would like to have a high resolution/vector image as the output which can be printed easily.

Comment: I will for sure, once I've written it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raphael is great for SVG, etc. http://raphaeljs.com

Answer (score 1):

To have a high resolution/vector image, you have to work with SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics), so far the web browser only support this. There are two ways you can do these.

- Looking up for canvas libraries. I prefer [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) as it supports SVG and animations as well.
- With HTML5 and its Canvas features also you can create such system.